# What's CellArray.GetNumberOfCells()?

Tags: vtk

I create a CellArray but no matter the input of it, it's GetNumberOfCells() is always 3. 
Why the result is 3?
Can I get the real number of cells?
Here is the test code.

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtkIdTypeArray

def calc_num_cells(cell_ids):
        cell_ids = np.concatenate(cell_ids)
        cell_array = vtk.vtkCellArray()
        cell_array.SetCells(vtk.VTK_LINE,
                            numpy_to_vtkIdTypeArray(cell_ids))
        print(cell_array.GetNumberOfCells())
calc_num_cells(
        [
                [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                [2, 4, 5],
                [2, 6, 7],
                [2, 8, 9],
                [2, 10, 11],
        ]
)
# output: 3

calc_num_cells(
        [
                [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        ]
)
# output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use `SetCells` in wrong way.
The first param of `SetCells` should be the num_cells.